# Is there a way to turn off microphone noise suppression?

Tags: microphone, noise-cancelling

I've started taking vocal lessons by skype recently and we've ran into unexpected problem: both me and my teacher need to pronounce long but quiet sounds as a part of breathing excersise, like long quiet shshshshshshshshsh pronounced as evenly as possible. 
And the problem is that either microphone or operating system filters out those sounds so on the other side it's just shsh........ and a lot of silence. 
I tried turning Ambient Noise Reduction off but it didn't change anything.

I have MacBook Pro with built in mic and latest Mac OS. My teacher has some windows notebook with built in mic as well.

Can someone think of any way to turn the noise suppression off, or any other workaround? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this using a chat program (e.g. Skype) since they will have some built-in noise cancellation. BTW, I think that Skype is the one messing with your audio.

You can do the following: whenever you have times that might be "handled" by the noise cancellation, then also activate recording (e.g. using Audacity). Then simply send the recorded file as an attachment to the chat. This way your teacher/you will hear the best high quality audio.